# actual date plus 14 days

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, datepicker

i working with swift 3 for osx.
i have this calendar:

[image]

this calendar should show the actual date plus 14 days.
Generally it is correct, because 30 - 16 = 14 days between.

this is my code for this:

```
datePicker.dateValue = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 14, to: Date())!
```

but at the bottom of my calendar should be visible the days between now and the selected date. but here will be shown 13 days.

why 13 and not 14?

this text label  will calculate like this:

```
txtDiffDays.stringValue = "(\(Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: Date(), to: datePicker.dateValue).day!) Tage)"
```

where is my mistake?

Comment: Surprisingly, if you do `let now = Date()` and replace `Date()` with `now`, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some experiments that I did in the playground:

[image]

```
let now = Date()
let date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 14, to: Date())!
let nowDay = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: Date()).day
let dateDay = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: date).day
date.timeIntervalSince1970 - Date().timeIntervalSince1970
date.timeIntervalSince1970 - now.timeIntervalSince1970
let days = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: Date().addingTimeInterval(-1), to: date).day!
let days2 = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: now, to: date).day!
```

Base on the result, I think what happens is that some time has passed between "setting the date picker's value" and "calculating the date difference". During both of these actions you did `Date()`. Since some time has passed, the date that he second `Date()` creates is a tiny little bit later than the one created by the first `Date()` call, as you can see from line 8 and 9 in the playground.

Since the second date is a little later, that makes the date difference a little less than 14 whole days, so `dateComponents` method rounds it down and you get 13.

To fix this, avoid doing two `Date()` calls. You can just create a local variable called `now` and use it throughout the method.

```
let now = Date()
```

Alternatively, you can use `Date().addingTimeInterval(-1)` like I did in playground line 10, but I feel like this is a cheat more than a solution.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are calling `Date()` twice.

When calculating the difference the `from date` must be the exact same date used when setting the datePicker. Otherwise it's slightly later and the amount of days is less than 14.